# How to enable SSL in Grails application using Jetty Plugin

Tags: ssl, grails, jetty, grails-plugin

I am trying to enable SSL for my application which uses Jetty plugin.

I have followed https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL and created my key and certificate using JAVA keytool, But no luck so far.

Please help me in running my application using https locally or provide me some good reference to achieve my goal.

I have created a custom configuration

as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
        <Arg>
          <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.http.ssl.SslContextFactory">
            <Set name="keyStore">/keystore-ssl.jks</Set>
            <Set name="keyStorePassword">password</Set>
            <Set name="validateCerts">false</Set>
          </New>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="port">8443</Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">30000</Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

and i am getting error

```
oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Config error at <Call name="addConnector"><Arg>|
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:86)
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me in achieving my goal.

https://www.blackpepper.co.uk/blog/jetty-runner-https-xml-configuration

Just need to put the required xml content into jetty-server.xml